# SharePoint -how to filter an XSLT Web Part from the browser

Tags: sharepoint

I am developing an Internet CMS site using WSS 3.0.

Basically, I have a Highlights list with properties ID, ColumnLeft, ColumnRight. I need the publisher to create new items and then show them in pages.

I need to show a single item of this list on custom HTML/ CSS, so I decided to use the Data Form Web Part (XSLT Web Part). My idea is to upload this web part to the gallery and made it available to the publisher -so she can add it to the pages.

But I am not sure how can I let the publisher filter the XSLT Web Part to show a specific item in the Highlights list. Ideally, I would like the publisher to see the list of available IDs and choose one.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI -my requirement was to let the publisher add a web part and set its properties. I used the SmartPart web part and extended its ToolPane class. Hope this helps somebody -I would be glad to post code if needed.